# Las tablas se corrompen en MYSQL: #1146 Table '...' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

Estoy teniendo muchos problemas para instalar en local una aplicación web antigua y con unas tablas enormes en mi nuevo trabajo.

Me he encontrado con una aplicación monolítica corriendo en una máquina virtual con Ubuntu, php v5.5 (PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.23) y mysql v5.5 (mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.47, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3).

El problema que estoy teniendo es que se me corrompen las tablas a las pocas horas de tenerlo todo instalado en local, apareciendo el mensaje en MYSQL "#1146 Table '...' doesn't exist" en cualquiera de las tablas cuando intento hacer un SELECT.

El problema creo que está en una tabla gigantesta que tiene más de 44 millones de registros, que cuando intento eliminar registros en local para dejar sólo los del último año, se queda MYSQL bloqueado en el borrado y no acaba nunca. He llegado a esperar más de 24h a que terminara de borrar sin lograr que finalice, así que mato el proceso y reinicio el servicio MYSQL y es cuando me da el error "#1146 Table '...' doesn't exist.

Uno de los procesos de borrado que acabé matando con un KILL, vi que el número de registros totales en la tabla iba disminuyendo hasta un punto en el que me mostraba una cifra mayor aunque después seguía bajando. Como si se hubiera reiniciado el borrado.

Este es el tamaño que tiene la tabla en el servidor de producción:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene una clave primaria compuesta de 3 campos:

- id_disp INT(11)
- Hora VARCHAR(45)
- Fecha DATETIME

Está claro que necesita un replanteamiento de sus índices y claves primarias que repercuten muchísimo en el rendimiento pero para ello necesito poder importar la base de datos en local. El problema es que se me corrompe enseguida y cada vez que tengo que importar tarda más de 24h en concreto la tabla Curva_Carga.

Dudas:
1 - ¿Por qué se puede quedar bloqueado MYSQL cuando borro registros en esta tabla gigantesca? He conseguido borrar registros de varios años pero con los de 2018 no terminaba nunca. Las limitaciones de MYSQL creo que no me afectan porque sobre el tamaño de las tablas es bastante más alto.

2 - ¿Por qué se puede estar corrompiendo todas las tablas con el reinicio de MYSQL cuando aparentemente se queda bloqueado con un borrado masivo?

3 - ¿Si añado un campo numérico autoincremental como clave primaria, podría mejorar el rendimiento? Tengo la duda porque sí que necesito esos 3 campos como índices únicos.

Mi máquina es un modelo actual con procesador "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700K CPU @ 3.80GHz 3.79 GHz"
y 32GB de RAM en Windows 10 PRO.

Gracias!

Comment: yo veo dos posibles soluciones, yo las he trabajado en sql server para casos similares de tablas muy grandes, pero tal vez te funcionen, la primera haz un ciclo en mysql y limita los registros a borrar a muy pocos registros, 10 o 20 por ciclo, y así no se saturara al intentar hacer una transacción tan grande, la segunda opción duplica la tabla por periodos y ve ingresando los registros de ese periodo en cada tabla correspondiente, y al final trunca esa tabla y renombra solo la que te interesa.

Comment: Buena idea! No lo había pensado. Lo que he hecho de momento es hacer un dump de registros de sólo el último mes, así que sólo tengo estos registros en mi BD en local. Pero para hacer una restructuración de la tabla al completo sí que tendría que importarla entera para probar en local, con el riesgo de que se corrompa en producción!